# SQL Overtime for Employees

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compose a code that will allow the employee to have another transaction for his OT even though he has a previous rejected Overtime transaction.

```
Employee_1 Shift: 9:00:00-18:00:00   OT Start Time: 18:00:00
```

Scenario 1
 example:

```
**Employee**: Employee_1    **Time:** 18:00:00-22:00:00    **Status:**  Rejected

**Employee:** Employee_1    **Time:** 18:00:00-20:00:00            
**Status:** (This should be allowed since previous transaction is rejected)
```

Scenario 2

```
**Employee:** Employee_1  **Time:**18:00:00-21:00:00   **Status:** Authorized

**Employee:**Employee_1   **Time:** 18:00:00-20:00:00  **[Status:][1]** (Overlapping not allowed) 



if exists(select 'X'   from Employee_OT_TBL tbl (nolock)            
where   tbl.ot_plan_date = @ot_plan_date          
and @ot_from_datetime < tbl.ot_to_datetime
and @ot_todatetime > tbl.ot_from_datetime 
and status = case when tbl.ot_status = 'REJ' then 0 else 1 end
and status = case when ot.doc_status = 'PEND' then 0 else 1 end )
```

Employee    OT Start Time   OT End Time Status
Employee_1  18:00:00    21:00:00    Authorized
Employee_1  18:00:00    20:00:00    Overlapping not allowed

Employee    OT Start Time   OT End Time Status
Employee_1  18:00:00    21:00:00    Rejected
Employee_1  18:00:00    20:00:00    For Authorization(This is allowed since previous application is authorized

Comment: please also include your table schema and sample data

Answer (score 0):

I had recently worked on [SQL for overlapping time periods](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-query-for-overlapping-time-periods-on-sql-server.aspx)

Please check the referred document to understand the solution in detail

I will suggest following SQL code for you.

You can remove the CASE statement and [OverLapping with Previous] column.

But the NewStatus field CASE is required. It checks whether overlapping occured and then read status of previous data row with [SQL Lag function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lag-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-previous-values.aspx)

Please test the query before you use in an UPDATE statement

```
select
 *,
 case when
  (ot_start between (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start))) or
  (ot_end between (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start))) or
  (ot_start < (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and ot_end > (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start))) or
  (ot_start >(lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and ot_end < (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)))
 then 
    'yes'
 when (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) is null
 then NULL
 else 'no'
 end as [OverLapping with Previous],

 case when
  (ot_start between (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start))) or
  (ot_end between (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start))) or
  (ot_start < (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and ot_end > (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start))) or
  (ot_start >(lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) and ot_end < (lag(ot_end,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)))
 then 
    case when  (lag([Status],1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) = 'Rejected' then 'Approved' else 'Rejected' end
 when (lag(ot_start,1) over (partition by employee order by ot_start)) is null
 then [Status]
 else [Status]
 end as [NewStatus]
from overtime
```

I only made a limited test. Here is the output

[image]